# Force Mac to stay in internal microphone source always

Tags: macos

I want my mac os (Catalina) to stay at the same microphone source(internal) all the time. When I connect AirPods to mac, the source switches to it and causes skipping sound.

What script should I write to force it to stay in the internal source?

Thanks

Comment: What app is using audio-in in your scenario? In that app's audio settings, see if its audio input device is set to something like "use system defaults", and switch it instead to the specific audio input device you want it to use.

Comment: actually no app needed for this, when airpods automatically connects, sound input changes instantly.

Comment: @bugrabaskaya did you find anything to solve this issue?

Comment: nope, couldn't find a solution, I still use the option + "sound source icon" and change the mic source. I tried to write a script but gave up pretty soon :D

Comment: Hey @Devrim and bugrabaskaya, I made an app to automate this very annoying process. It's called Recadio. It's a paid app, but I'll happily share a 50% discount code if you reach out at dgrcode[at]gmail.com. Sorry for not sharing links/discounts here, but don't want to come across as spammy.

Answer (score 0):

I use High Sierra, but I understand there has not been any change to how audio is managed.  In MacOS under Applications/Utilities select "Audio MIDI Setup".

When the program launches if it is not immediately displayed go to the "Window" drop down and select "Audio Devices"

Displayed are the various audio & sound devices available.  Select the "Built-in Microphone" device and either right click on this item or click on the gear at the bottom of the device list and select "Use This Device For Sound Input"  Ensure the master volume is not muted or value set to zero.

Quit the "Audio MIDI Setup" Application.
You can now check in the system preferences under sound and it should show that the internal microphone is set for audio input.

Comment: no, this does not make it stay at a specific source.